# Eureka registration based on ip and not machine name

Tags: spring, virtual-machine, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

My eureka server is up and running.

I have two copies of the same virtual machine that has my Eureka client in it ready to run.

When one eureka client tries to register at the server, it overrides the other client - registration is 'successful' but I have only one instance of the client instead of two instances.

my clients are registering using the machine name which is obviously the same for the two VMs.

**Is there a way make registration based on mac address or IP instead of machine name?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is `eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true'. [Check this out](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/a7398842078319dcaa353a708c12bb7b9fa85a4e/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-netflix.adoc#prefer-ip-address)